# Disable warning about literal commas in qw list

Tags: perl

```
my @flavors = qw/sweet,sour cherry/;
```

yields

> Possible attempt to separate words with commas

How can I disable that warning in cases where I want literal commas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Disable the [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) locally:

```
my @flavors;
{
    no warnings 'qw';
    @flavors = qw/sweet,sour cherry/;
}
```

Or, separate out those with commas:

```
my @flavors = ('sweet,sour', qw/cherry apple berry/);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `no warnings 'qw';`.

```
my @x = do {
   no warnings qw( qw );
   qw(
      a,b
      c
      d
   )
};
```

Unfortunately, that also disables warnings for `#`. You could have `#` mark a comment to remove the need for that warning.

```
use syntax qw( qw_comments );

my @x = do {
   no warnings qw( qw );
   qw(
      a,b
      c
      d   # e
   )
};
```

But it's rather silly to disable that warning. It's easier just to avoid it.

```
my @x = (
   'a,b',
   'c',
   'd',   # e
);
```

or

```
my @x = (
   'a,b',
   qw( c d ),  # e
);
```

Comment: Interesting, why backslash does not disable this warning: `qw# . \, : #`

Comment: That returns `.`, `\,` and `:`. If anything, that would warrant an additional warning!

Answer (score 5):

Just don't use `qw//` but one of the plenty other quoting operators, paired with a `split`. How does `q//` sound?

```
my @flavours = split ' ', q/sweet,sour cherry/;
```

The `qw//` is just a helpful shortcut, but it's never *necessary* to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In a case where I was developing a framework where lists of comma separated keywords was pretty commonplace, I chose to surgically suppress those warnings at the signal handler.

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    return 
        if $_[0] =~ m{ separate words with commas };
    return CORE::warn @_;
};
```